# Getting "TypeError: $(...).css(...) is undefined" despite using if statement to filter out all undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this function, which is supposed to store the background-color of all td's in a table. Some td's will not have a specified background-color. Those that don't, are to be skipped, they shall not be stored. However I'm having trouble achieving this, I get this error in my FireFox console:

```
TypeError: $(...).css(...) is undefined
```

In the code below, you'll see that I'm trying to skip td's that don't have the background-color attribute. But the program goes ahead anyway and keeps returning this error anyway.

```
var canvasString = '';
for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        var attr = $('#' + x + '-' + y).attr('background-color');
        if (attr !== 'undefined') {
            if ($('#' + x + '-' + y).css('background-color') !== 'transparent' && $('#' + x + '-' + y).css('background-color') !== null && $('#' + x + '-' + y).css('background-color') !== 'undefined') {                          
                canvasString = canvasString + x + ' ' + y + ' ' + ($('#' + x + "-" + y).css('background-color')).replace(/\s/g, '') + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById('canvas').value = canvasString;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `if (x !== 'undefined')` does not test if the variable is undefined; it tests if the variable equals the *string*, `'undefined'`. To test if a variable is undefined use

```
if (typeof x !== 'undefined') ...
```

However, there are other problems with your code. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here, but try this:

```
var ele = $('#' + x + '-' + y);
if (ele.length) {
    canvasString += x + ' ' + y + ' ' + ele.css('background-color').replace(/\s/g, '') + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checks for undefined are wrong. When a value is undefined, it's not equal to the string `"undefined"`. The type of the value is equal to the string, like this:

```
if (typeof attr !== 'undefined') {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a more native jQuery solution, you could do something like this:

```
function getBackgroundColors(colNo) {
  var row = 1;
  return $('table td').map(function (i, el) {
    var color = $(el).css('backgroundColor');
    if (color !== 'transparent') {
      obj = {row: row, col: i % colNo + 1, color: color};
    }
    if (i % colNo === 1) row++;
    return obj;
  });
}

console.log(getBackgroundColors(2));
```

This would yield you an array of cell objects specifying the row, the column, and the colour, like:

```
[Object { row=1, col=1, color="rgb(239, 239, 239)"}, Object { row=1, col=2, color="rgb(239, 239, 175)"}, Object { row=2, col=1, color="rgb(239, 239, 175)"}, Object { row=2, col=2, color="rgb(239, 63, 239)"}
```